# how to change name=${file##*/} in python to name=${*/}

Tags: python, git-bash

so i dont know python, but trying to work out this script to search all m3u8's instead of just 1 of the same name in both folders.

For Example i would like to use all_streams.m3u8 in one folder
and then use pluto.m3u8, Freeview.m3u8, yt.m3u8, and any other m3u8 that are in the 2nd folder..

So it would merge the all_streams.m3u8 with pluto.m3u8, freeview.m3u8, yt.m3u8 and any other m3u8's

These 2 scripts are meant to merge m3u8's and remove the all the excess junk from the files so that the main file can be read using any player.

Heres the 2 scripts, the bash and python:-

merge_m3u8_files_in_dirs.sh

```
#!/bin/bash


### Helper script to merge m3u8 files


#########################################
##### START OF FUNCTION DEFINITIONS #####
#########################################
merge_m3u8_files () {
    local m3u8_merge_into_file=$1
    local m3u8_merge_from_file=$2
    local json_check_file=$3

    echo "### START Processing - '${m3u8_merge_into_file}' ###"

    ls -alt "${m3u8_merge_into_file}"
    ls -alt "${json_check_file}"

    python "${SCRIPT_PATH}/merge_m3u8_files.py" --merge_into_file "${m3u8_merge_into_file}" --merge_from_file "${m3u8_merge_from_file}"

    if [[ $return_code -eq  0 ]];
    then
        echo "   No Issues"
    else
        echo "   Issues Found"
    fi
    echo "### FINISH Processing - '${m3u8_merge_into_file}' ###"
}
#######################################
##### END OF FUNCTION DEFINITIONS #####
#######################################

echo '##### Calling: '`basename "$0"` '('$0')'

### Verify the parsed variables
echo Verifying passed arguments

m3u_merge_into_dir=$1
m3u_merge_from_dir=$2

if [[ -z ${m3u_merge_into_dir} ]];
then
    echo "arg1 - M3u Merge into directory is not set"
    exit 1
fi

if [[ ! -d ${m3u_merge_into_dir} ]];
then
    echo "Directory '${m3u_merge_into_dir}' DOES NOT exist." 
    exit 1
fi

if [[ -z ${m3u_merge_from_dir} ]];
then
    echo "arg1 - M3u Merge from directory is not set"
    exit 1
fi

if [[ ! -d ${m3u_merge_from_dir} ]];
then
    echo "Directory '${m3u_merge_from_dir}' DOES NOT exist." 
    exit 1
fi

### Action ###

SCRIPT_PATH="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" >/dev/null 2>&1 && pwd )"

# find "$m3u_merge_into_dir/" "$m3u_merge_from_dir/" -printf '%P\n' | sort | uniq -d
for file in $m3u_merge_into_dir/*.m3u8; do
    name=${file##*/}
    if [[ -f $m3u_merge_from_dir/*.m3u8 ]]; then
        echo "$name exists in both directories, process"

        merge_m3u8_files "${m3u_merge_into_dir}/${name}" "${m3u_merge_from_dir}/${name}"

    fi
done
```

merge_m3u8_files.py

```
"""Script to convert iptvcat json files to m3u8."""

import argparse
import os
import sys

sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..'))

from ez_m3u8_creator import m3u8


def main():
    """Run the main function."""
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-mi', '--merge_into_file', help='The file to merge into', required=True)
    parser.add_argument('-mf', '--merge_from_file', help='The file to merge from.', required=True)
    args = parser.parse_args()

    print('merge_into_file', args.merge_into_file)
    print('merge_from_file', args.merge_from_file)

    if (not os.path.exists(args.merge_into_file)) or not os.path.isfile(args.merge_into_file):
        raise ValueError(F'"{args.merge_into_file}" is not a vaid file')
    if (not os.path.exists(args.merge_from_file)) or not os.path.isfile(args.merge_from_file):
        raise ValueError(F'"{args.merge_from_file}" is not a vaid file')

    m3u8.merge_m3u8_files(merge_into_path=args.merge_into_file, merge_from_path=args.merge_from_file)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

i've tried to find the answers, but can't seem to find an answer that works...

For example the normal *.m3u8 doesnt work, sadly i dont know enough of python to get it to work..